# Scrolling using SetScrollInfo API

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, richtextbox

I'm using SetScrollInfo API to scroll text inside my richtextbox(winforms). I have a timer and each tick I need to scroll by one pixel. 
Everything is working perfectly on shorter texts. On longer texts, the scroll method scrolls more than 1 pixel. I think it is related to the limited parts of scrollbar. I quess there is a max of 65536 parts, but maybe I'm wrong. 
Problem occurs when si.nMax = 65535 after calling GetScrollInfo()

Is there any sollution to scroll by one pixel on longer texts?

```
// Scrolls a given textbox. handle: an handle to our textbox. pixels: number of pixels to scroll.
    void scroll(IntPtr handle, int pixels)
    {
        mScrollsCounter++;
        IntPtr ptrLparam = new IntPtr(0);
        IntPtr ptrWparam;
        // Get current scroller posion

        SCROLLINFO si = new SCROLLINFO();
        si.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(si);
        si.fMask = (uint)ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL;
        GetScrollInfo(handle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_VERT, ref si);

        // Increase posion by pixles
        if (si.nPos < (si.nMax - si.nPage))
            si.nPos += pixels;
        else
        {
            ptrWparam = new IntPtr(SB_ENDSCROLL);
            t.Enabled = false;
            SendMessage(handle, WM_VSCROLL, ptrWparam, ptrLparam);
        }

        // Reposition scroller
        SetScrollInfo(handle, (int)ScrollBarDirection.SB_VERT, ref si, true);

        // Send a WM_VSCROLL scroll message using SB_THUMBTRACK as wParam
        // SB_THUMBTRACK: low-order word of wParam, si.nPos high-order word of wParam
        ptrWparam = new IntPtr(SB_THUMBTRACK + 0x10000 * si.nPos);
        SendMessage(handle, WM_VSCROLL, ptrWparam, ptrLparam);
    } 
struct SCROLLINFO
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public uint fMask;
            public int nMin;
            public int nMax;
            public uint nPage;
            public int nPos;
            public int nTrackPos;
        }
```

Comment: Look at the MSDN article for WM_VSCROLL.  The scroll position is encoded as the hi-word of wparam.  A 16-bit value.  Which inevitably means that it can't be more than 65535.

Comment: Is there any way how to detect how many pixels was scrolled in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the number of pixels encoded in `WM_VSCROLL` (which you are presumably passing to your `scroll()` function as the `pixels` parameter), use the `nTrackPos` member of the `SCROLLINFO` structure.